# Como generar números aleatorios (float) en c

Tags: c, random

Necesito generar números aleatorios pero que este en el rango de 0 a 7.5 (0.075).
Hasta el momento tengo esto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  int i;
  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%1.3f\n", (float)(rand() % 60)/80);
  printf("\b\b \n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

```
0.650
0.488
0.400
0.387
0.138
0.387
0.712
0.313
0.013
0.650
```

Comment: ¿ Hasta `7.5` o hasta `0.075` ? Son bien distintos los números.

Comment: Lo siento es de 0 a 7.5

Answer (score 3):

Para añadir decimales a un número, basta con dividirlo entre `1` seguido de tantos `0` como decimales necesitemos:

```
7777 / 1     = 7777
7777 / 10    = 777.7
7777 / 100   = 77.77
7777 / 1000  = 7.777
7777 / 10000 = 0.7777
```

Por lo tanto, `7.5` se puede expresar como `75 / 10`, o como `750 / 100`, o incluso como `7500 / 1000`.

Con esto en mente, podríamos pensar que nos basta con hallar un número aleatorio entre `0` y `75`, y dividir el resultado entre 10. Sin embargo, esto presenta un *inconveniente*:

> 7.000
>   2.600
>   3.200
>   3.300
>   1.400
>   1.100
>   2.600
>   4.900
>   0.800
>   5.700

Como se observa, las cifras *variables* a la derecha del punto decimal tienen poca *resolución*: solo **1** dígito.

La solución: *ampliar* el rango: en lugar de `75 / 10`, usar `7500 / 100`, obteniendo este resultado:

> 6.024
>   0.564
>   5.101
>   2.045
>   4.023
>   6.731
>   3.457
>   1.452
>   7.162
>   5.153

El código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( ) {
  srand( time( NULL ) );

  for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
    printf( "%1.3f\n", ( rand( ) % 7501 ) / 1000.0f );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Listo  muchas gracias , me sirvio.